# One shot manga featuring an apocalyptic world where creatures wreak havoc on the citizens and MC is the last remanding survivor of a clan

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for this manga, which is a one shot. It's about an apocalyptic world where creatures wreak havoc on the citizens and the citizens killed, sold them off but it will corrupt them except for our main character who is the last remanding survivor of a clan who do not get corrupt. I think there's a girl sent out but that's pretty much what I remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found it myself. It's ***[Mujou no Sekki - Ouma no Ketsumyaku](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/473i79e/mujou-no-sekki-ouma-no-ketsumyaku)***, written and drawn by Hosokawa Shingi and published in 2014.